# javascript : making a factory item display proper value on the field containing music albums set

Tags: javascript, object, set, factory

"singerAlbum" and "musicCollection" are objects. The setter albums in musicCollection is for creating new singerAlbums. The problem is: when creating two distinct musicCollections, and creating a singerAlbum in one of the musicCollections, it also appears in the second musicCollection, though it hasn't been added there. 
the code(javascript):

```js
let singerAlbum = {
  Name: undefined,
  get name() {
    return this.Name;
  },
  set name(value) {
    this.Name = value;
  }
};

let musicCollection = {
  Name: undefined,
  Albums: new Set(),
  get name() {
    return this.Name;
  },
  get albums() {
    return this.Albums;
  },
  set name(value) {
    this.Name = value;
  },
  set albums(value) {
    let album = createSingerAlbum();
    album.name = value;
    musicCollection.Albums.add(album);
  },
};

function createSingerAlbum() {
  return Object.create(singerAlbum);
}

function createMusicCollection() {
  return Object.create(musicCollection);
}



let collection1 = createMusicCollection();
let collection2 = createMusicCollection();
collection1.albums = "Abbey Road";
console.log(collection1.albums);
console.log(collection2.albums);
```

The result is:

```
Set {Object {Name: "Abbey Road"}}
Set {Object {Name: "Abbey Road"}}
```

The result I want to achieve is :

```
Set {Object {Name: "Abbey Road"}}
Set {}
```

Comment: If you will run the provided code, you will see 2 empty objects as outputs and not the provided result

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I ran it in node, though and got something closer to the given result. It appears that the snippet runner has a poor quality `console.log`

Comment: It looks like you want to create some Sets?

This is how I would approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.create` gives a new object, with the object you pass to it set as the new object's prototype. If an object doesn't have its own property set with a value, it uses the value from its prototype. That's exactly what is happening here.

In addition, your albums setter is setting the value directly on `musicCollection` (the prototype), but you probably wanted to set a value on `this` (the current object).

But since you are mutating an existing object (Albums), and because each collection object uses the prototype's `Albums` object instead of it's own, those changes will be changed across all collection objects created with `createMusicCollection`.

In order to get around this, you need to create a new `Albums` object for each collection object. That's where constructors come in handy. Normally, you would use the `class` syntax and define a `constructor` method to do this when creating an object with `new`. But since you are using factory methods, we can do it there. Here's how I would recommend modifying your code if you want to keep using `Object.create`:

```js
let singerAlbum = {
  Name: undefined,
  get name() {
    return this.Name;
  },
  set name(value) {
    this.Name = value;
  }
};

let musicCollection = {
  Name: undefined,
  // since we need to make a new album object each instance, don't make it here
  Albums: undefined, 
  get name() {
    return this.Name;
  },
  get albums() {
    // we could check to see if `this.Albums` is defined before returning it,
    // but let's create it in the "constructor" method instead
    return this.Albums;
  },
  set name(value) {
    this.Name = value;
  },
  set albums(value) {
    let album = createSingerAlbum();
    album.name = value;
    this.Albums.add(album);
  },
};

function createSingerAlbum() {
  return Object.create(singerAlbum);
}

function createMusicCollection() {
  let collection = Object.create(musicCollection);
  collection.Albums = new Set();
  return collection;
}



let collection1 = createMusicCollection();
let collection2 = createMusicCollection();
collection1.albums = "Abbey Road";
//modified to print a bit nicer in the snippet viewer
console.log("collection1:", ...collection1.albums); 
console.log("collection2:", ...collection2.albums);
```

In general, the only things you want to define on your prototype are immutable objects, such as functions and strings, numbers, etc. Arrays, objects, sets, maps, and the like are mutable, and if you are planning on mutating them, you probably want a different copy for each instance of the object.

See also:

- [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)
- [Inheritance in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)

Comment: This explanation is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach it.

```js
class Album {
  constructor(name, artist) {
    this.name = name
    this.artist = artist
  }
}

class Collection {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.albums = new Set()
  }
  addAlbum(name, artist) {
    this.albums.add(new Album(name, artist))
  }
}

const bettlesCollection = new Collection('Bettles Collection')
bettlesCollection.addAlbum('Abbey Road', 'The Beetles')
bettlesCollection.addAlbum('Sgt. Pepper...', 'The Beetles')

console.log(bettlesCollection)
```